# call function from outside the noConflict scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call the function `startCountDown()` but I get `TypeError: startCountDown is not a function`

bellow is my code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
    $(function(){
        var duration = "<?php echo $kk_details22['duration'];?>" * 60;
        startCountDown(duration);

        function startCountDown(duration){

            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
                until: +duration,
                format: 'HMS',
                layout: '<div id="timer">'+
                    '<div id="vals">'+
                        '<div id="h" class="numbs">{hnn}</div>'+
                        '<div id="m" class="numbs">{mnn}</div>'+
                        '<div id="s" class="numbs">{snn}</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div id="labels">'+
                        '<div id="hl" class="labs">hours</div>'+
                        '<div id="ml" class="labs">mins</div>'+
                        '<div id="sl" class="labs">secs</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>',
                 onExpiry: submitkk
            });     
        }
    })
})(jQuery);

function submitkk() {
    $("#timeAlertModal").modal('show');
    startCountDown(60); # give one more minute
}
```

Comment: you could make `startCountDown` a global e.g. `window.startCountDown = function ...`

Comment: JavaScript has lexical scope. `startCountDown` is not in the same scope as `submitkk`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to define your function within the onload event, unless you are wanting to prevent people from executing the function in the console or from 3rd party libraries, move the function declaration to the global or outer scope, or your `submitkk` function to the inner scope. You could (and probably should) add your form handler programmatically, I can't see where you are using it, but I assume it's something like: `<form onsubmit="submitkk();">..`, add it from your onload handler:

```
$('#your-form').on('submit', submitkk);
```

Ensure that load order is correct and it might help to capture the return of noConflict:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script>
  var myJquery = jQuery.noConflict();
  (function($) {
    $(function(){
      var duration = "<?php echo $kk_details22['duration'];?>" * 60;
      startCountDown(duration);

      function startCountDown(duration) {
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
          until: +duration,
          format: 'HMS',
          layout: '<div id="timer">'+
              '<div id="vals">'+
                  '<div id="h" class="numbs">{hnn}</div>'+
                  '<div id="m" class="numbs">{mnn}</div>'+
                  '<div id="s" class="numbs">{snn}</div>'+
              '</div>'+
              '<div id="labels">'+
                  '<div id="hl" class="labs">hours</div>'+
                  '<div id="ml" class="labs">mins</div>'+
                  '<div id="sl" class="labs">secs</div>'+
              '</div>'+
          '</div>',
           onExpiry: function() {
             $("#timeAlertModal").modal('show');
             startCountDown(60); # give one more minute
           }
        });     
      }
    })
  })(myJquery);
</script>
```

Comment: I moved the function `submitkk` to the inner scope, but the same issue raises modal: `TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`

Comment: That's a different issue, and likely due to how your scripts are being loaded. Now it seems that your whatever library `modal` comes from isn't loaded or is having issues with the `noConflict` call (which is giving up ownership of the `$` var. Ensure that your load order is: 1. jquery 2. jquery plugins 3. the code you posted. I'll update my post to make it more clear